# File.ReadAllText use of CACHE

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know behavior for method File.ReadAllText
Here an example of my code:

```
uxJavaScriptTinyMCEDisplayer.Text = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("TinyMCEJavaScriptAdmin.txt"));
```

File.ReadAllText have some CACHE behavior? So taht the first time the file is read, will be kept in memory and not re-read again?

thanks

Comment: That's up to your operating system. Depending on memory conditions and file size, it might be cached in memory for a while, but you shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: @Frédéric I just checked the source of the ReadAllText method with Reflector and couldn't see any cache used anywhere, just tracked it down to calling `ReadFile` method in `kernel32.dll` - on what conditions can it be cached?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, I meant the OS itself performs the caching, at an even lower level than `ReadFile()`. Raw disk reads can be kept in memory so subsequent read requests for the same data don't need to hit the disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct caching in .Net, however, you get caching behaviour indirectly via the OS.

Windows is very much optimized to cache file contents in memory and has a layer that facilitates in-memory caching of file system contents. But as Frédéric points out in his comment, you should not rely on this behaviour as memory pressure, cache ageing, etc, may mean that cached content is dropped.

The OS does a good job of caching if there is plenty of memory.

**Update**

This is an old article (Win2K) but gives some idea as to OS disk caching.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742613.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No cache. It will read the current contents of the file at the given path.